# Removed Feature: Hyperlinks from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part

Tags: reporting-services, export-to-excel, ssrs-2012

i am working with SSRS 2013 and i have problem when i want to export my report that has hyperlinks to some pages. This happens only in Excel, and not in CSV when i have larger amount of data(more than 50 000 rows, in each row is one hyperlink to some Username).

Here is the error log message that i get when i want to Export to Excel:

> error237240_01.xmlErrors
>   were detected in file
>   'E:\VIP.xlsx'Excel completed file
>   level validation and repair. Some parts of this workbook may have been
>   repaired or discarded.Removed Feature: Hyperlinks from
>   /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml
>   part

What may be the problem i how can i resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

I guess you have invalid URL hyperlinks.

I don't really know SSRS, but mabye following docs here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/add-a-hyperlink-to-a-url-report-builder-and-ssrs will solve your problem

I had similar problem (from another source, not SSRS) with `Removed Feature: Hyperlinks` - maybe this helps you:

I've found out, that I've had invalid hyperlinks in sheets.

For some hyperlinks there were two hyperlinks with `Target` like:
hyp1) `http://www.domedomain.org, www.anotherdomain.com`
hyp2) `https://www.example.com http://www.sometnihg.net http://www.test.com`
(invalid hyperelinks)

I've changed it to following:
hyp1) `http://www.domedomain.org`
hyp2) `https://www.example.com`
(real valid hyperlinks)

And all seems working now.

You can unzip a xlsx file and find xml file
`/xl/worksheets/_rels/sheet1.xml.rels`
with hyperlinks defined like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">
    ...
    <Relationship Id="rid1" Target="http://www.example.com" TargetMode="External" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/hyperlink"/>
    <Relationship Id="rid2" Target="http://www.example2.com" TargetMode="External" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/hyperlink"/>
    ...
</Relationships>
```

and look for Target attribute content